# Include StackPrinter app on trilogy sites?

Tags: feature-request, stackapps

I found myself using the [StackPrinter application](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) fairly often, so I wondered if it should be included on all sites. A tiny grey "print" button per question would be enough, and would quickly prompt the user to save the printed PDF.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a cool browser like Chrome or Firefox, you could use [StackPrinter greasemonkey script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/77298).
This script adds a Tiny grey "print" button per question as requested.

[image]

If you are unlucky and your browser of choice is not Chrome or Firefox, you could use the bookmarklet (available on [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) homepage).

Regarding the Trilogy request, thank you for that proposal but it's hardly feasible for two main reasons:

1. StackPrinter is using StackExchange API that has a 10.000 calls per-day limit [shared among all the apps that currently are hosted on GAE](https://stackapps.com/questions/1713/google-app-engine-apps-we-are-all-on-the-same-quota).
2. StackPrinter is running on GAE without billing (limited resources)

Anyway, It will be cool to try :P

Comment: I do use Chrome, but I think this should be added for all uses and without any hassle. I hate configuring my PCs, just like everyone. --- The 10k API limit is something the SO guys can surely take care of. I'm tempted to say it's a piece of cake to provide a new special key to StackPrinter and other verified, useful apps. --- I don't know about GAE but I strongly suspect there is a solution for that part, too.

Comment: @maf "The 10k API limit is something the SO guys can surely take care of".. are you sure? http://stackapps.com/questions/1713/google-app-engine-apps-we-are-all-on-the-same-quota

Comment: Oh... I see. That's wicked.